# How to disable scrolling of webview containing facebook like button

Tags: android, scroll, facebook-like, android-webview

I tried to implement facebook like button in my android application. I am using a webview with limited width and height to show like button and disable its scrolling. I want to show like button only.

Here is my WebView in xml

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView2"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:scrollbars="none" />
```

and my like button is

```
private String getFacebookLikeUrl() {
        return "http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?"
                + "href="
                + URLEncoder
                        .encode("http://www.facebook.com/otcmeds")
                + "&layout=standard" + "&show_faces=false" + "&width=50"
                + "&action=like" + "&colorscheme=light" + "&font=arial"
                + "&access_token=" + URLEncoder.encode(accessToken);
}
```

Disable webview's scrolling by using following code

```
        webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

        webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                return (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
            }
        });
```

Now my problem is when clicking more than once on like button **it scrolls to left and hides some part of like button**. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What problem you are facing then?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be zooming in when tapping more than once in the WebView.  Try setting `WebSettings.setSupportZoom` to false and see if that fixes your problem.  [Documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html).